# How to fix WordPress white screen after login to administration panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, I've tried to:

1. Disable plugins and themes;
2. Increase memory limits;
3. Check for failed auto-update;
4. Switch on debugging.

The only thing I get is the next message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: wp_support in
>   /path/to/mywebsite.com/www/wp-includes/template.php on line 741

It is the latest WordPress + I don't have an access to my server configuration, only files through FTP.

It's a frequent problem, but in my case standart solutions didn't work.

Comment: `It is the latest WordPress` which version it that? which php version are you running?

Comment: I would install Wordfence and scan site for changed files. My WP 5.1.1 version of template.php does not contain `wp_support`

Comment: @kuh-chan 5.1.1, I don't know which php version it is.

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo How can I install Wordfence if I don't have an access to administration panel because of the white screen?

Comment: Sorry. But the file was changed. You might compare directory to a known good site.

Comment: the `template.php` should have only 709 lines of code: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.1-branch/wp-includes/template.php

Comment: @kuh-chan okay, it is because of security plugin, I have allowed it to change certain files, but this is just a notice. If I comment the rest of lines, then the white screen is still there.

Comment: ehm... what "security plugin"? do you have a name/link? what's about replacing all files with the original files?

Comment: @kuh-chan it is called [iThemes Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/). I've tried to replace all files with the original ones, but everything is still the same.

Comment: Get a clean copy of Wordpress and replace everything except the content of wp-content.

Comment: Try reinstalling WordPress: Dashboard > Updates > Re-install Now.

Comment: @dave thank you, I'll try to do that and let you know the results.

Comment: @cabrerahector I don't have an access to my dashboard, it shows the white screen.

Comment: @dave wow! Thank you very much! It did help. How can I mark your answer?

Comment: Added as an answer instead of a comment if you want to mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a clean copy of Wordpress and replace everything except the content of wp-content.